# Use Google Search Appliance results as my own application

Tags: asp.net, google-search-appliance

How can I format my XML base search results which I am getting using GSA client library and show it onto any page of application like Google search appliance test center?

I am unable to find good example which will fit as solution.

Provide me if any reference code is available.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Search Appliance Test Center is simply a couple of dropdowns that construct an iFrame.  I wouldn't use it as an example to build an application.

To build an ASP.NET application, you could use [GSALib](http://gsalib.codeplex.com/).  It's a C# wrapper to the XML API which will allow you to bind it to typical ASP.NET controls.  You could also consumer it via JSON/JSONP via adding [this](https://github.com/michaelcizmar/GSJSON) stylesheet to a frontend.  Then you could consume it as a restful service.  If you have a more specific question, I'd be happy to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSL transformation to convert XML obtained from GSA into HTML. For an ASP.NET example refer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469723/Rendering-XML-Data-as-HTML-using-XSL-Transformatio

Comment: Please add some example in here